# Flutter payment gateway for marketplace app

Tags: flutter, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, marketplace

I am working on a marketplace app. it has services offered by merchants. app requirement is that when user purchase any services then system needs to pay the merchants their service charge and take the commission for listing the service. i am using razorpay for now but open to adapt other option as well. i have implemented the checkout flow and on successful payment amount goes into the system account. My concern is that how i am gonna to make the payout to the merchants now. i have gone through all the docs (Route API and RazorpayX API) but couldn't find it convincing. Although they have api for transfer and refund but as it will be a separate transaction therefore they will charge the transaction fees again here. i am not sure if am following the right approach. any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working with Razorpay directly to understand how to best handle transaction fees with their API.

If you’re open to using Stripe, the marketplace app you’ve described sounds like a good use case for [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). How you decide to handle payouts to merchants will ultimately depend on how you set up the Connect platform and the [types of charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) you use.

Comment: Really appreciate, i had to talk in person with razorpay to understand the integration and transaction fee. Stripe is great for marketplace app but not for Indian users I guess.